# Python: Only using part of a shapefile

Tags: python, python-3.x, gis, shapefile

I am using Python 3.6 to create a map that shows precipitation data in North America. The code I have so far extracts my data inside of a `shapefile` and then plots it on a map.

My problem is that the `shapefile` I have downloaded contains the shapes of all of the continents. I was wondering is there a way I could only read in the North American continent from my `shapefile`?

If this isn't a possibility then does anyone know where I could download a `shapefile` that only has North America? Thank you!

This is the part of my code that reads the `shapefile`:

```
import shapefile
sf=shapefile.Reader('continents')
```

This is the [link](http://www.arcgis.com/home/item.html?id=3c4741e22e2e4af2bd4050511b9fc6ad) for the shapefile.

Comment: Please add more details to be able to help you. What have you tried so far? How does that shapefile looks, does it have any attributes that may help (dont just share a link)?

Comment: I have tried adding the name of the continent to the end of the shapefile. For example sf=shapefile.Reader('continents','North America') and sf=shapefile.Reader('continents/North America'). Doing this changes nothing, I am still only seeing a map with all the continents. I included the link in my question so that people can download the shapefile I am using and read the txt file that comes with it that shows all attributes, since it is too large to copy and paste here. @GrayCygnus

Comment: I downloaded your shapefile, I am currently working on an aswer, posting it shortly

Comment: Done, you may also want to check [GIS Stack Exchange](https://gis.stackexchange.com/) where there are Q&As of subjects related to GIS

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Taking a look at the shapefile you mentioned we can see that it has one attribute in its Attribute Table (which is "CONTINENT"). Therefore, we need to search for all the shapes and select those that match the continent you desire (North America), like this:

```
import shapefile

#read the shapefile
sf=shapefile.Reader('continent.shp')

#obtain shapes and its records
#the shapes are the actual coordinate points 
#the record contains all attributes related to each shape
shape_records = sf.shapeRecords()

#search for the ones with desired records
#this shapefile has only one attribute calles CONTINENT
desired_shapes = []
for s in shape_records:
    if s.record[0] == 'North America':
        desired_shapes.append(s.shape)
        #or do whatever you want with that element s.shape is the actual shape
```

If you want take a look at [this](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pyshp) page that describes the usage of `shapefile`. It is useful to use a tool (like QGis) to see what attributes your data has so you can then proceed to detect them programmatically.

Comment: Great, you can also check [OSGEO](https://pcjericks.github.io/py-gdalogr-cookbook/) to handle shapefiles, it is the one I currently use, instead of `pyshp`, as it has more options and documentation.